# cannot create iOS folder on my react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am asking this question for the third time and I don't get it why no one even tries to help on this, is this question not well explained? If you can ask for more information I can give!

I am having trouble created iOS folder inside my react native app(detached) as when I created the app I created it from windows machine and iOS folder didn't come when I wrote: **exp detach**

Now that I have got a macOS, how can I get to create iOS folder so I can use that to build from xCode. I tried **react-native upgrade**, this is telling me that I have some version conflicts, so I don't want to upgrade it actually, I just want to have iOS folder on my react native.

What would be the best solution in here?

Comment: Are using asking about how to add the folder `ios` in your app directory or something else? You probably didn't receive an answer because your question is vague.

Comment: yes I am asking how to add folder iOS on my app directory, do u have any idea?

Comment: well, I know that I can add it using exp detach if I am in a macOS and by running react-native upgrade, but the idea is that at the time I created my app I was using windows, now that I have to build it for iOS too, the upgrade command makes me problem with version conflicts, so I don't wanna upgrade it, just need iOS folder created so I can build it on Xcode! I hope I am clear, if not then God help me!

Comment: open `Terminal`, cd <to-parent-dir>, type `mkdir ios`. That'll create the folder in the place you want it.

Comment: are you kidding?

Comment: I need an iOS folder that react native packager creates it along with Xcode stuff, how am I suppose to import that on Xcode with nothing in it?

Comment: No, I'm not kidding. That's why I asked if you needed a folder `or something else`. Apparently, it's the latter. I don't have a specific answer for your dilemma. I'm just trying to provide possible troubleshooting ideas. I haven't personally encountered this issue. I understand your frustration. But let's not "bite the hand that feeds".

Comment: thanks for your attempting to help, but I think by just purely creating a iOS folder does not solve the issue!

Comment: apparently I seem to have solved this issue by running exp detach again in macOS over detached app \and it created the iOS folder and all the neccesarly files needed for build! at least I am building it successfully now.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I tried **exp detach** over my detached app and it created iOS, it's working! hopefully this will help anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

**Step I: Ensure below installable are installed**

- Java Sdk Android Studio
- Xcode (in case of OSX)
- HomeBrew (in case of OSX to install node)
- Node/NPM (Node runs Javascript outside the browser. NPM is used for    installing and managing Dependencies. Node and NPM come
  together)

Those are some essential installs that you will need in your Project

**Step II: **
For windows/OSX you need to run the following commands in your command prompt/command line:

This is the important part for running a react native project:

**Step II: **

> npm install -g react-native-cli

Then you can use this cli to start a new project like this:

**Step III: **

> react-native init

Hope this helped you, please vote..